# How would I delete the same item from UI and localStorage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an item of a ToDo app both from the UI and `localStorage` when its delete button is clicked. I can remove the item from the UI when e.target.calssName === 'delete'. However, I can't access the index of the array in `localStorage` and delete the same item from there as well. Here is the code I am working on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
const addTask = document.querySelector('#addItem');
const inputForm = document.querySelector('#inputForm');
const saveButton = document.querySelector('#saveButton');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

// Add task button
const addItem = () => {
    inputForm.style.display = 'block';
    taskInput.focus();
};

// Add and update item to localstorage
const checkStorage = () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('#taskInput');
    if(input.value) {
        const task = {
            name: input.value
        };
    
        if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
            const tasks = [];
            tasks.push(task)
            localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
        } else {
            const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
            tasks.push(task);
            localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};

// Display item on UI
const displayItem = () => {
    const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    if(tasks !== null) {
        const html = tasks.map((task, index) => {
            return `
            <ul class="item" id="${index}">
                <li>${task.name}</li>
                <button class="edit" id="${index}">Edit</button>
                <button class="delete" id="${index}">Delete</button>
            </ul>
            `
        }).join('');   
        output.innerHTML = html; 
    } else {
        checkStorage();
    };
};

// Save the task and display the item
const saveTask = (e)  => {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkStorage();
    displayItem();
    inputForm.reset();
    inputForm.style.display = 'none'
};

// Delete item from UI and localStorage
const deleteItem = (e) => {
    const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    // Not sure how to loop throuh the tasks array and delete the item which is deleted from the UI
}

document.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
document.addEventListener('onload', displayItem())
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveTask);
addTask.addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

Comment: How do you know which index to remove? I don't see any code that deals with removing elements from the page.

Comment: I am struggling to get the index. Any suggestion how do I get the index of a specific object? I have tried looping though the localstorage array and get the index but I can't get a specific item with it's index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#splice` to delete an element from an array.

```
const deleteItem = (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains("delete")){
       const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
       tasks.splice(+(e.target.getAttribute("id")), 1);
       localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works. Could you please explain this line of code specially what does the + do there?

```
tasks.splice(+(e.target.getAttribute("id")), 1);
```

Comment: `+e.target.getAttribute("id")` gets the id of the button and converts it to a number. `tasks.splice(index, 1)` removes 1 element from the array starting at index.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! Really really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

many different ways to do this.best way is to user `filter`. More about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> ```
> var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
> tasks = tasks.filter(task=> "your condition");
> localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
> ```

Note: if you have the the id of the task it should go like this.

> tasks = tasks.filter(task=> task.id != id );